# Windows 10 Taskbar / Cortana / Start Menu do not work after some time after restarting pc

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu, cortana

I have Windows 10 and I am encountering a consistent problem with the start menu, taskbar and cortana that prevent clicking on either start menu or cortana, or right clicking on icons in the taskbar.

I seem to have come across many proposed fixes but do not have a successful method found yet to resolve the issue.

One such method found was to run the following via powershell.

> Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage
>   -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Short of reinstalling or constantly resetting my machine to have temporary access to the start menu / cortana / taskbar or downgrading my build, what can I do to get this problem fixed?

Comment: Does it happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: The start menu responds along with cortana and taskbar in safe mode as I just rebooted into safe mode.

Comment: This might be unrelated but I uncovered some answers indicating Avast AntiVirus is related to the issue so I have uninstalled and will see if it occurs again.

Comment: If it works in Safe Mode, then something is being started in a normal boot, that causing it.  So use Autoruns and through trial and error determine which program it is.

Comment: Did this start after the Mar 1 updates to Windows 10? (KB3139907 and KB3140743). It did for me.

Comment: Sorry for late response but I have been observing the issue since the second latest OS build.  When I refresh the pc to a previous build the problem goes away.  You would think for a critical and frequently used component such as the start menu the product would be robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, after uninstalling Avast Antivirus and finally encountering the issue consistently after about 5 minutes from starting up the PC, I decided to take a drastic measure.  I abandoned Cortana and the start menu and installed Classic Shell.  Now at least I get a start menu that works.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and resolved it by rolling back the Conexant audio driver.

Windows 10 will reinstall the incompatible driver with every udpate, so you will need to roll back the driver after every update.

Open Device Manager/Sound, Video and Game Controllers, open Properties for the Conexant driver, and select Roll Back Driver from the Driver tab.

Comment: Unfortunately for my computer I have a different audio driver (Realtek Audio Driver) that shows the roll back option as greyed out.